# How do I view web traffic on an iOS device?

Tags: ios

I’m working on an iOS app that compares stores such as Target, Sam’s Club, and Walmart. My app uses code that replicates what their websites do to get all the product information in a `JSON` or `XML` format.

### Issue

Some of the other stores that I want to include in my app at first glance don’t have a way to get an items product information. But some have an app, take H-E-B for example. Their app somehow gets all the product information in a format that can be converted into Swift 4.

### Possible Solution

H-E-B’s app is obviously getting the content of a `URL`, and that will include the data I need. I’m almost 100% sure that their is some type of log. I would like to know how to view this log.

Comment: https://www.charlesproxy.com/

Answer (score 1):

There's no log file of the requests, but you can use a proxy app such as [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) to have a look at the traffic of other apps.

Charles and mitmproxy both can also intercept web traffic on iOS devices. You need to install them on your Mac and configure your iOS proxy settings. For details, have a look at [Charles' FAQ, Section "iOS"](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/).

This works even for HTTPS traffic, as long as the app doesn't use public key pinning as a countermeasure.

Comment: there is no charles for iOS :) i think he is trying to intercept connections from mobile app.

Comment: Yes, you install Charles not on iOS but on your Mac, but it also works for iOS. I edited the answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good practice. Even if you are able to view the logs somehow, the APIs might get changed tommorow and your app will stop working.

If you are trying to list products from different stores then you must ask that stores if they provide any APIs for product details. Otherwise intercepting the logs and finding out ways is not a good practice unless you are making it for fun.

There is one solution which you can use. Make you own app server whose responsibility will be collect that data for the app. So that you can change it on the fly if there are any changes in your providers. This is a possible solution but not recommended.

Comment: Reverse-engineering the native app's protocol probably isn't the most stable solution, but it can work well enough. The last two sentences of your answer however are not correct: With a proxy, it is definitely possible to intercept web traffic, and if you import the certificate that is generated by your proxy, this even works for SSL/TLS connections. See my answer for details.